# sudo: python: command not found

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I want to make `sudo python` find Python 3.

I had a strange issue where, in terminal, typing `python --version` gave 3.6 but `sudo python --version` gave 2.7. After trying a few things I finally uninstalled 2.7 with `sudo apt-get purge python2*`. That removed everything correctly. Still, I can't get `sudo python` to find Python 3.

I've tried changing my `/root/.bashrc` to have:

```
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

and

```
alias python="/home/username/anaconda3/bin/python"
```

and I put the same lines in `~/.bashrc` too.

My `etc/sudoers` has this line:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"/usr/bin:$
```

I've opened new terminals and even restarted the computer. Any ideas how to make `sudo python` just find Python 3? I don't want a single session fix but something that will work each time I use the terminal.

Thanks

Comment: `sudo` doesn't respect aliases. It can't, because an alias is a shell operation, but `sudo` is not part of the shell (can't access internal shell state), and directly calls the operating system's `execve()` call to invoke software being called.

Comment: That said -- `sudo env PATH="$PATH" python` should do the trick.

Comment: Which file would I have to put that in? Or would I have to type it each session?

Comment: Every time you run `sudo python`, but if you're doing that all the time... err... that's a smell. (Not quite a "code smell", necessarily, but let's call it a "bad-practice smell").

Comment: that said, put `psudo() { sudo env PATH="$PATH" "$@"; }` in your `.bashrc` and call `psudo` instead of `sudo`, and there you are.

Comment: Do you know a persistent way to fixing it?

Comment: That should work but does that mean there's no nice way of getting it to work with just `sudo`?

Comment: Uh. "nice" meaning what? You could take the PATH override out of `/etc/sudoers`, of course, but that's there for good reasons, so I don't particularly advise it. (Also, `sudoers` configuration has a lot of moving parts, and I'm not convinced that a question about Python is the right place to go into it -- probably better to find another question asking *explicitly* how to make `sudo` not override the PATH, if that's how you want to go about this).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your `/etc/sudoers` is explicitly configured to override your user's path with a known, secure one.

That said, if you want to always path the user's PATH through, you can easily override `sudo` with a function that will do this (installed in your `~/.bashrc` or similar to make it persistent):

```
psudo() { sudo env PATH="$PATH" "$@"; }
```

thereafter, `psudo python` will use the same `python` interpreter that would be found in the PATH.

---

If you *really* want to override the `sudo` command itself, that's doable too:

```
sudo() { command sudo env PATH="$PATH" "$@"; }
```

The `command` builtin prevents the function from recursing (calling itself).

Comment: That `psudo` solution is a great compromise. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to modify your bashrc, you can always do this: 
`sudo env "PATH=$PATH" python something`

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer suggests setting up functions to duplicate or replace `sudo`, with syntax new Linux user might find complex.

There is a simpler way...

User has miniconda3 python env:

```
(base) user@machine:~/$ which python
/home/user/miniconda3/bin/python
(base) user@machine:~/$ python --version
Python 3.9.12
```

`sudo` can not see python:

```
(base) user@machine:~/$ sudo which python
(base) user@machine:~/$ sudo python --version
sudo: python: command not found
```

Simply use "which python" in place of "python"!:

```
(base) user@machine:~/$ sudo `which python` --version
Python 3.9.12
```

This allows the shell interpreter to replace "python" with "/home/user/miniconda3/bin/python" in the `sudo` command.

Alternatively, set an environment variable, say `PY` to *always* use in place of `python` - this has the advantage of being usable inside shell scripts:

```
(base) user@machine:~/$ export PY=`which python`
(base) user@machine:~/$ $PY --version
Python 3.9.12
(base) user@machine:~/$ sudo $PY --version
Python 3.9.12
```

Note: `sudo` with `--preserve-env=PATH` is attractive, but does not work, because `sudo` uses `secure_path` from `/etc/sudoers` to look up executables, *not* $PATH.

Comment: This awesome answer should be the accepted one

Answer (score 2):

#### ...other approach.

when I got to this post, I was just looking to run:

`python -m spylon_kernel install`

as I ran the command above, I got a message telling me to use `sudo` in addition to what I was typing, such as

`sudo python -m spylon_kernel install`

as I did it, I got the '*sudo: python: command not found*' message from console, and adding *--user* such as:

`python -m spylon_kernel install --user`

was simply enough to get it done.

> Notice that I did not use `sudo` command within the last command.

Answer (score -1):

If python 3.x is installed already, try the following code

```
sudo python3
```