# Open and read txt file from USB

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pyusb

I'm using Linux. I know my USB name is:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8564:1000 Transcend Information, Inc. JetFlash
```

and the    idVendor and    idProduct is:

```
idVendor           0x8564 Transcend Information, Inc.   
idProduct          0x1000 JetFlash
```

Where is the problem? Code or other stuff missing?

I read over the [PyUSB: reading from a USB device (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73151914/pyusb-reading-from-a-usb-device-2), and other scenario but not really same as mine so give a hand pls.

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor= 0x8564, idProduct=0x1000)

ep = dev[0].interfaces()[0].endpoints()[0]
i=dev[0].interfaces()[0].bInterfaceNumber
dev.reset()

if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(i):
    print("hello")
```

The output from linux command (usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied):

[image: the output from linux command (usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied )]

- *tried with 'sudo python The_one_i_want.py'*

[image: tried with sudo python The_one_i_want.py]

the output is

> sudo: python：找不到指令
> sudo: python: command not found

I just checked my sudo is working:
[image: sudo is working]

the output after I tried , `sudo python The_one_i_want.py`now the output shows

> python: can't open file '/home/joy/fe_dir/The_one_i_want.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> [image: can't open file]

but file `The_one_I_want (new).py`   `The_one_I_want.py` is inside `/fe_dir` directory tough

updated tried: now is 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'usb''  , how to solved from here?
[image: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'usb']

Comment: try with sudo ... or add your user to an appropriate group (maybe "dialout" or something?) although if your gonna use sudo why not just mount it and read from it as a normal drive?

Comment: Try to run pip install usb as root. because usb may not be installed for root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run with `sudo`

```
sudo python The_one_i_want.py
```

Because the error you got says that you don't have permission to do that.

Comment: hi, @TheGoldenTree , still not working for that

Comment: Ok well i found the same question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44726377/sudo-python-command-not-found
There are many reasons why you may get this error. so i think the answers in this question may be helpful.